# Python Pandas: Replace NaN with neighboring value

Tags: python, pandas

I need to analyze a Dataframe, which bases on recorded data of an experiment. Each row of my dataframe resembles a measurement with given recording frequency.

Since every measurement took a different amount of time, there were lots of NaN values. I would like to replace now those cells to bring my dataframe to an equal number of entrys.

Due to the characteristics of my measurement the value NaN would mean a measurement of the value in the column left of it. I was recording the position of an object. When the object stopped moving, the measurement was stopped as well.

For that purpose I iterated over each column and when the value is NaN i wanted to replace it with the value left of it. k is the number of columns, u the number of rows. i and v are running numbers of row and column:

```
while v < u
    i = 0
    while i < k:
          if df.loc[v][i] == NaN:
             df.iat[v][i] = df.loc[v][i-1]
          i = i + 1
    v = v + 1
```

I tried it with multiple commands (e.g. pd.isna.df.iloc[v,i]) but none of it works. Could you help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mind showing what the dataframe currently looks like `print(df.head())` or similar, and then showing what you would like it to look like? Would make it easier to understand the question.

Comment: At the moment, the dataframe looks very unhandy, since it does not have any header. My datalogger just sums up the measured values separated by a semicolon to import it as a csv. It is value1;value2;value3;value4;value5;NaN;NaN... I would like to have: value1;value2;value3;value4;value5;value5;value5

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`fillna(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
new = df.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)
```

This would fill all your columns when blank, with their respective value on the left.

Better should be `ffill` only:

```
df = df.ffill(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did do the trick!

Comment: @Flo - yop, or less typing solution with same ouput `df = df.ffill(axis=1)` - check another answer.

Comment: @sophocles - I dont see comment, because need @ in my name ;)

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[left_col])`

Comment: For that, I'll guess, I need to iterate through all column names?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).